# Python : Taberror

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, indentation

I have one Estonian script, but It gives me error:

```
    Sorry: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (function sheet1.py, line 8)
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

and code is:

```
import sys
import datetime
end = False
while end == False:
def contin01():
    print("Kas soovid jätkata?")
    exit = input("Vali [1] - JAH // Vali [2] - EI: ")
    if exit[0] == "1":
        print("********* Beginning of Line ********* ")
    elif exit[0] == "2":
        sys.exit()
def sina():
    nimi = input("Kirjuta enda nimi: ")
def guest_name():
    Guest_Name = input("Sisesta kliendi nimi: ")
def guest_arrival():
    Arrival = input("Sisesta kliendi saabumiskuupäev: ")
def guest_dep():
    Departure = input("Sisesta kliendi lahkumiskuupäev: ")
def room():
    Room_number = input("Sisesta kliendi toa number ")
def special():
    req = input("Kirjuta kliendi erisoovid, kui puuduvad pane "-": ")
def WU():
    wake = input("Kirjuta mis kell soovib klient äratust")
def date():
    päev = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y T%H:%M")
```

can't find the problem - tried deleting and trying again but nothing changes

Comment: Everything under the while loop at the top isn't even intended correctly in the question

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your source code. "Use 4 spaces per indentation level" according to [Python PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation). If you mix tabs and space within one indentation context (e.g. function), you will get the warning, you mentioned.

The following source code is badly formatted (where `<SPACE>` stands for a space character and `<TAB>` stands for the horizontal tab):

```
def func(x):
<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>if x == 6:
<TAB><TAB>return 1
<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>return 42
```

will give the following error:

```
  File "test.py", line 3
    return 1
           ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

whereas the following program is correct:

```
def func(x):
<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>if x == 6:
<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>return 1
<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>return 42
```

BTW, `while end == False` should be written `while not end` and requires an additional indentation level in the following line.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that functions ideally should not be defined within a loop